# Are there any Firebase Console desktop clients?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

The browser console runs very slowly for me.

I usually have a page open on a project's database page and another one on its functions log.

I was wondering if there are any (safe) alternatives to the online console?

Comment: No, there are no alternatives that fully replace the console.

Comment: When you say 'runs very slow', what does that mean exactly. What part is 'slow'?

Comment: @Jay - The initial loading of the page (when the firebase animations plays), the loading of new logs (maybe this is normal tho), sometimes the DB does not automatically refresh and is generally slow (clicking into a node for example). I understand that this might be normal because of the underlying operations but I'm not sure

Comment: You can watch the Cloud Functions logs with the Firebase CLI too. But in my experience this is not necessarily faster than using the console.

Comment: If you use VSCode, I tend to use this extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsayol.firebase-explorer). Usually loads faster and avoids some context switching.

Comment: @bastien - This one is really nice! You can post that as an answer if you'd like, I'll take it (and it's a generally useful one as many use VS code)

Comment: @RedKnight91 sure! You just want to be careful about the permissions you grant to the extension (it's all read only if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use VSCode, the [Firebase Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsayol.firebase-explorer) extension usually loads faster and avoids some context switching.

Answer (score 2):

Have found this twice from google so thought I would update with this tool

https://firefoo.app/

14 day free trial but so far it's worth the small monthly fee